# Client-side hashing/salting over HTTPS

Tags: javascript, https, login-script, cryptographic-hash-function

I'm wondering what the serious issues are with the following setup:

Username/password login scheme
Javascript/ajax requests the salt value from the server (we have established in previous questions salt is not a secret value)
Javascript preforms an SHA1 (or otherwise) of the password and salt.
Javascript/ajax return the hash to the server
The server applies another salt/hash on-top of the the one sent via ajax.

Transactions are over HTTPS.

I'm concerned about problems that may exist but can't convince myself that this is that bad of a setup. Assume that all users need javascript enabled as jQuery is heavily used on the site. It's basically attempting to add an additional layer of security to the plain-text of a password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that effort of passing salts and hashes between the client and server is already built into the underlying HTTPS/SSL protocol. I would be very surprised if a security layer in javascript is going to help very much. I recommend keeping it simple and use plaintext over SSL on the client-side. Worry about encryption on the server-side.

Answer (score 3):

As always: be very careful about designing cryptographic protocols yourself.

But that being said, I can see the advantage in the scheme. It *will* protect against the password being revealed through a man-in-the-middle-attack and it *will* ensure that the server never sees the actual password, thus preventing some inside attacks. On the other hand it does not protect against man-in-the-browser, fishing etc.

You might want to read through [RFC 2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) about HTTP Digest access authentication. That scheme is similar to what you propose.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't add any additional security.  The JavaScript code is present in the client, so the hashing algorithm is known.  You gain nothing from doing a client-side hash in this case.

Also, there's no reason why the client should know about the hashing salt.  It actually *should* be a secret value, especially if you're using a shared salt.

Comment: The salt would not be shared against users.

Answer (score 1):

I'll 100% disagree with the accepted answer and say that under no circumstances should an original password ever Ever EVER leave the client. It should always be salted and hashed. Always, without exception.

Two reasons...
. The client should not be relying that all the server components and internal networks are TSL. It is quite common for the TSL endpoint to be a load balancing reverse proxy, which communicates with app servers using plaintext because devops can't be bothered to generate server certs for all their internal servers.

. Many users are pathologically inclined to use a common password for all of their services. The fact that a server has plaintext passwords, even if only in memory, makes it an attractive target for external attack.

Answer (score 0):

You're not gaining anything. There's no point to a salt if Joe Public can see it by clicking View > Source, and the old maxim about never trusting client input goes double for password hashing.

If you really want to increase security, use a SHA-2 based hash (SHA-224/256/384/512), as SHA-1 has potential vulnerabilities. NIST no longer recommends SHA-1 for applications that are vulnerable to collision attacks (like password hashes).

Comment: Password hashes aren't vulnerable to collision attacks http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_attack#Attack_scenarios